# method provided to orElse() does not execute altogether

Tags: java, android, java-8, option-type

In the below code, I am trying to understand the concept of Optional offered in java-8. I created the below example to grasp the principle behind the orElse().
After executing the code, the body of defaultMethod() was executed, and returned

```
new User("DEFAULT_USER", "default@gmail.com", "0000", null);
```

to object y. the log statement printed the correct data as I expected it to do.

The question is, why all the logs, inside defaultMethod() were not printed?? is orElse() was introduced to return values only without executing the whole body of the provided method.?

**code**:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    User user_1 = this.getUser_1();
    User user_2 = this.getUser_2();
    User user_3 = this.getUser_3();

    User y = OptionalsUtils.toOptional(user_1)
            .map(u1 -> this.getUser_3())
            .orElse(this.defaultMethod());
    Log.i(TAG_LOG, "orElse->y: " + y.getUserName());

}

private User getUser_3() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    list.add("espn");
    list.add("qtv");
    list.add("der Spiegel");
    list.add("deutsch welle");

    User user = new User();
    user.setUserName("johannas");
    user.setUserEmailAddres("joha90@gmail.com");
    user.setUserId("2345");
    user.setUserFavoritesTvList(null);
    return null;
}

private User defaultMethod() {
    Log.w(TAG_LOG, "defaultMethod is called1");
    Log.w(TAG_LOG, "defaultMethod is called2");
    Log.w(TAG_LOG, "defaultMethod is called3");
    Log.w(TAG_LOG, "defaultMethod is called4");
    Log.w(TAG_LOG, "defaultMethod is called5");
    Log.w(TAG_LOG, "defaultMethod is called5");
    Log.w(TAG_LOG, "defaultMethod is called5");
    Log.w(TAG_LOG, "defaultMethod is called5");

    return new User("DEFAULT_USER", "default@gmail.com", "0000", null);
}
```

**log**:

```
2018-12-17 12:46:15.774 20158-20158/com.example.optionals_00 W/ActMain: defaultMethod is called1
2018-12-17 12:46:15.774 20158-20158/com.example.optionals_00 W/ActMain: defaultMethod is called2
2018-12-17 12:46:15.774 20158-20158/com.example.optionals_00 W/ActMain: defaultMethod is called3
2018-12-17 12:46:15.774 20158-20158/com.example.optionals_00 W/ActMain: defaultMethod is called4
2018-12-17 12:46:15.774 20158-20158/com.example.optionals_00 W/ActMain: defaultMethod is called5
2018-12-17 12:46:15.774 20158-20158/com.example.optionals_00 W/ActMain: defaultMethod is called5
2018-12-17 12:46:15.774 20158-20158/com.example.optionals_00 I/ActMain: orElse->y: DEFAULT_USER
```

Comment: Is it possible the logger decided not to log some of the Strings you passed to it, since you passed the same String 4 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an issue related to `orElse`. Those two lines missing are being skipped by `Logcat` because they are identical.

If Logcat detects repeated logs, it will show only the first and the last one, and in between you should be able to see a message similar to this one:

> 04-16 03:24:21.591 I: uid=10085(u0_a85) xxx.yyy.zzz identical 2 lines

This behavior started in the version `3.1` of Android Studio. An [issue was opened](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77305804) to solve this, because many people didn't like it, so it was removed in the version `3.2` of Android Studio. Therefore, if you use Android Studio `3.0` or `3.2`, all your logs, even if they are identical, should be displayed.